# Where to add a Clickable Row in a Fragment (Android)

Tags: android, android-activity, row, fragment, clickable

Newbie Android question here.  I am using the new Fixed Tabs + Swipe provided in the ADT package.  It sets it all up nice and neat for you.  I have added 4 tabs or fragments in to the action bar and am at the point where it is time to configure the fragments themselves, like adding buttons, tables links and what not.  I have added a table to the first fragment.  This table is very similar to the "Settings" table in the root Android OS. The table is a network connections table which will control turning the BT and Wifi radios on.  In the OS table, the row had a 'switch' to control the BT or Wifi Radio state.  Additionally you can click on the row and it will forward you to another View/activity to see the listings of networks found.  I am trying to get the row to be clickable and then add the method that will tell the row what to do when clicked.

I am confused, does the OnClickListener go in the fragment itself or does it go in the Main where the pager is located?  Would seem to me that it would go into the fragment itself as it belongs to it.  Since the "extends Fragment" does not use buttons or any of the bundle from Activity, this is where I am getting killed.

Here is the xml excerpt from the fragment with my table row:

```
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="rowClick" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxHeight="10dp"
                android:maxWidth="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wifi" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:text="@string/wifi"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="24dp" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/tbWifi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/wifitogglebutton"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </TableRow>
```

You can see that I have added both an id to the row and also the 'clickable' attribute. SO when a user clicks on this row as in the operating system settings tab, he/she should be forwarded to another layout where they can see a list of available networks.  The standard fragment as provided by ADT is as follows:

```
    import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TableRow;

public class SettingsActivity extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container,
                false);

        return rootView;

    }

}
```

If it is useful, then my MAINACTIVITY which calls the fragment for this tab is as follows:

```
// Tab1 Settings Tab
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings,
                    container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

I hope that my question makes a little sense.  The old tabs seemed much easier.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better choice is you can use `OnClickListener`  in `fragment` itself, then only you can `re-use` this `fragment` in some other `activity` without `implement` `OnClickListener` again .

Comment: ok, but where in the Fragment should it go?  That is where I am having a problem.

Comment: within the getview method.

Comment: I hope this is not too dumb, but there is currently not a getView.  There is only onCreateView(